# "Server" to "Server" ZeroMQ communication

Tags: c, zeromq

I want to build a system that has the following architecture:

```
+------------------+          +------------------+
| App1. 0mq client | <------> | App2. 0mq server |
+------------------+          +------------------+
```

where
<kbd>**`App2`**</kbd> is a `ZeroMQ` server and it's a black box,
 and
 <kbd>**`App1`**</kbd> is a `ZeroMQ` client, but it is in fact a frontend server. The frontend server will process some requests from the clients and then will communicate with the <kbd>App2</kbd> server.

**Given that:**

1. At any point in time any of the "servers" can go down or be restarted.
2. I want to start any of the apps, even if the other app is not running.
3. If <kbd>App1</kbd> is started when <kbd>App2</kbd> is down, I want to know when <kbd>App2</kbd> is up.

**Is it possible to implement 3. only using `ZeroMQ` builtins**, or do I need to use a different mechanism to notify <kbd>App1</kbd> that <kbd>App2</kbd> is up **?**

Comment: Does App2 really needs to notify App1? Wouldn't it be sufficient if on a regular base App1 polled/checked whether App2 is back up again?

Comment: Well, first let's agree that a *"server"* and *"client"* roles are **not meaningfull abstractions for modern distributed systems**. Rather important is to explicitly state and disambiguate, whether a "black box" indeed means you have a zero chance to add/modify such App-only or whether the whole host is locked from any additions, that one might propose to help on (1), (2) and (3), ok? In case one is capable of and having a reasonable degree of freedom, ( *almost* ) anything can be done with ZeroMQ tools.

Comment: Victor, are you ready to decide on the value of the answers provided and accept the best one? This is the way StackOverflow works, isn't it?

Comment: Still not decided, @Victor, when to click an Accept at the best Answer provided :o)?

Answer (score 2):

### `Item 3`: using pure `ZeroMQ` built-ins

**`Fig.1:`** Why it is wrong to use a naive **`REQ/REP`**

```
               XTRN_RISK_OF_FSA_DEADLOCKED ~ {  NETWORK_LoS
                                         :   || NETWORK_LoM
                                         :   || SIG_KILL( App2 )
                                         :   || ...
                                         :      }
                                         :
[App1]      ![ZeroMQ]                    :    [ZeroMQ]              ![App2] 
code-control! code-control               :    [code-control         ! code-control
+===========!=======================+    :    +=====================!===========+
|           ! ZMQ                   |    :    |              ZMQ    !           |
|           ! REQ-FSA               |    :    |              REP-FSA!           |
|           !+------+BUF> .connect()|    v    |.bind()  +BUF>------+!           |
|           !|W2S   |___|>tcp:>---------[*]-----(tcp:)--|___|W2R   |!           |
|     .send()>-o--->|___|           |         |         |___|-o---->.recv()     |
| ___/      !| ^  | |___|           |         |         |___| ^  | |!      \___ |
| REQ       !| |  v |___|           |         |         |___| |  v |!       REP |
| \___.recv()<----o-|___|           |         |         |___|<---o-<.send()___/ |
|           !|   W2R|___|           |         |         |___|   W2S|!           |
|           !+------<BUF+           |         |         <BUF+------+!           |
|           !                       |         |                     !           |
|           ! ZMQ                   |         |   ZMQ               !           |
|           ! REQ-FSA               |         |   REP-FSA           !           |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~ DEADLOCKED in W2R ~~~~~~~~ * ~~~~~~ DEADLOCKED in W2R ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|           ! /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\|         |/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/!           |
|           ! \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/|         |\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\!           |
+===========!=======================+         +=====================!===========+
```

---

**`Fig.2:`** How to implement requirement **`Item 3`**, using pure `ZeroMQ` builtins.

**`App1.PULL.recv( ZMQ.NOBLOCK )`** and **`App1.PULL.poll( 0 )`** are obvious

```
[App1]      ![ZeroMQ]
code-control! code-control           
+===========!=======================+
|           !                       |
|           !+----------+           |         
|     .poll()|   W2R ___|.bind()    |         
| ____.recv()<----o-|___|-(tcp:)--------O     
| PULL      !|      |___|           |   :   
|           !|      |___|           |   :   
|           !|      |___|           |   :   
|           !+------<BUF+           |   :     
|           !                       |   :                           ![App2]
|           !                       |   :     [ZeroMQ]              ! code-control
|           !                       |   :     [code-control         ! once gets started ...
|           !                       |   :     +=====================!===========+
|           !                       |   :     |                     !           |
|           !                       |   :     |         +----------+!           |
|           !                       |   :     |         |___       |!           |
|           !                       |   :     |         |___| <--o-<.send()____ |
|           !                       |   :<<-------<tcp:<|___|   W2S|!      PUSH |
|           !                       |   :    .connect() <BUF+------+!           |
|           !                       |   :     |                     !           |
|           !                       |   :     |                     !           |
+===========!=======================+   :     +=====================!===========+
```

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not expert but I once implemented a similar platform.

An additional layer of signaling (**`REQ/REP`**) from <kbd>**`App2`**</kbd>**`->`**<kbd>**`App1`**</kbd> could do that.

Everytime <kbd>`App2`</kbd> comes online, a **`msg`** should be conveyed to <kbd>`App1`</kbd>.

A separate thread in <kbd>`App1`</kbd> would be able to receive this `msg` from <kbd>`App2`</kbd> anytime.

Comment: With all due respect, `REQ/REP` is a risky pattern, as it fails to detect, the less to resolve an internal **F**inite-**S**tate-**A**utomata mutual deadlocking. Pieter HINTJENS wrote countless posts about this **un-avoidable** risk always present on intrinsically unreliable transport-class use-cases.