# ZeroMQ: are PUB/SUB topic subscriptions cheap?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq, jzmq

**Problem:** I have a number of file uploads coming via HTTP in parallel ( uploads receiver ). I'm storing them temporarily on a local disk. Another process ( uploads submitter ) gets notified about new uploads and does specific processing ( parsing, extracting metadata, uploading to S3 etc ). Once upload processing done I want uploads receiver to be notified by submitter to reply back with status ( whether submission is ok or error ) to the remote uploader. Using ZeroMQ PUB/SUB pattern, what would be better:

- subscribe all upload receiver threads to a single topic. Each
  receiver thread would have to filter messages based on upload id or
  something to find a notification that belongs to it.
- subscribe each receiver thread to a new topic which represents
  particular upload. This one seems more reasonable assuming topics are
  cheap in ZeroMQ, i.e. not much resources is needed to keep them and they
  can be auto-expired. I expect new uploads to come at dozens of
  files per second, single upload processing may take up to several
  seconds so theoretically I can have up to thousand of topics active
  at the same moment of time. Also I may not always be able to
  unsubscribe due to various failure modes.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm tired so forgive me if I'm rambling, but wouldn't asynchronous request-reply suit your use case better than pub-sub, given the fact you can't be sure you'll unsub? On topic - subscribing is cheap, but nothing is infinite and if you can't clean up, you're bound to get screwed at some point.

Comment: With respect to your proposal, **`REQ/REP`** scheme is awfully dangerous in use-cases, where a selected transport-class, together with other points-of-failure, increases levels of uncertainty of a message/signal delivery ( the primary `REQ/REP` archetype is prone to falling into it's own, un-salvageable FSA-deadlock ). If interested, may like to check other posts on this risk of the `REQ/REP` Finite-State-Automaton self-locking >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/38163015/3666197 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### <sup>Initial notice:</sup>
 On Using Different ZeroMQ Version Numbers:

While more recent versions may use **`PUB`**-side topic filtering, the early ZeroMQ versions did use **`SUB`**-side approach, which means that all the ( network ) message-transport traffic goes to all `SUB`-s as an acceptable penalty for distributing the processing-workload, that would otherwise be needed to get handled at lowest possible latency on the `PUB`-side.

This is important for cases, where in an open distributed system association the homogenity of versions is not enforceable.

Whereas you design architecture seems to be co-located on the same `<localhost>` the performance impact remains non-distributed ( concentrated )  and may implicate just some limited latency/priority tweaking, if overall bottleneck appears during this Use-Case up-scaling.

---

### On Scaleability Ranges - Limits are still farther than your Use-Case:

As Martin Sustrik ( ZeroMQ co-father ) presented in details, ZeroMQ was designed with expected scales up to some small tens of thousands:

> *(cit.:)* " **Efficient Subscription Matching**
>   In ZeroMQ, simple tries are used to store and match `PUB/SUB` subscriptions. The subscription mechanism was intended for up to 10,000 subscriptions where simple trie works well. However, there are users who use as much as 150,000,000 subscriptions. In such cases there's a need for a more efficient data structure. "

[Further details **on design & scaling** might be found interesting in this Martin's post.](http://250bpm.com/blog:19)

---

### The Best Next Step?

A fair approach would be to mock-up each of the questioned approaches and benchmark them, scaled to { 1.0x , 1.5x, 2.0x, 5.0x } of the expected static scales in-vitro to have quantitatively supported data about real overheads, performance and latencies relevant to the alternative strategies under review.

Anyway, Vovan, **enjoy the worlds of smart signalling/messaging in the distributed processing.**